# Connecting to GCP redis Memory Store from the GKE pods

Tags: ssl, redis, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-memorystore

I have created gcp redis memory store in an vpc network with

```
Security
AUTH Enabled
TLS Enabled
```

I followed https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting_to_a_redis_instance_that_uses_auth this article and i am able to connect to the memory store from compute engine.

But when i try to connect from the GKE

Cluster Information

```
Version 1.16.15-gke.7800
VPC-native traffic routing  Enabled
```

i am getting the following Error

```
read tcp X.X.X.X:59408->X.X.X.X:6378: read: connection reset by peer
```

ultimatly i want to be able to use redis memory store from the GKE pods.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a document how to connect Redis from GKE https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-gke... Have you seen this? Are you flowing all steps mentioned there?

Comment: yes, i am using the exact steps and the code as well. Since redis memory store is TLS and AUTH enabled i am not sure the code given will work as it is in the article.

Comment: Well it might be hard, but maybe add some more details like: what kind of app is it? How do you test the connection? Is this something reproducible?

Comment: Since you enabled `TLS` on the memory store , ensure client is also using tls while creating the connection.  We saw similar issue and the moment we enabled the TLS on client side , the issue went away